# How to add a modal to delete an element in a foreach loop in laravel?

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog

I have a loop showing different students, and in every line I have a delete option. I want to write a modal to ask the user if he really wants to delete the element. If I make the loop like this:

```
@foreach($days as $day)
                        <tr>
                            
                            <td>{{$day->name}}</td>
                            <td>
                              <form method="POST" action="{{route('days.destroy',$day)}}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar día">
                                @csrf
                                @method('DELETE')
                                <button class="btn btn-danger">
                                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M2.5 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1H3v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h.5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H10a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H2.5zm3 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM8 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7A.5.5 0 0 1 8 5zm3 .5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"/>
                                    </svg>
                                    Eliminar
                                </button>
                              </form>
@endforeach
```

the day is deleted with no modal, but if I add a modal like the following:

```
@foreach($days as $day)
                        <tr>
                            
                            <td>{{$day->name}}</td>
                            <td>
                              
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path d="M2.5 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1H3v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h.5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H10a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H2.5zm3 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM8 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7A.5.5 0 0 1 8 5zm3 .5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"/>
                                </svg> 
                                Eliminar
                              </button> 

                              <!-- The Modal -->
                                      <div class="modal" id="myModal">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                                          <div class="modal-content">

                                            <!-- Modal Header -->
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                              <h4 class="modal-title">¿Desea eliminar?</h4>
                                              <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
                                            </div>

                                            <!-- Modal body -->
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                              Si pulsa el siguiente botón, se eliminará el día. Si cierra esta ventana, no se eliminará.
                                            </div>

                                            <!-- Modal footer -->
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                              <form method="POST" action="{{route('days.destroy',$day)}}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar día">
                                                @csrf
                                                @method('DELETE')
                                                <button class="btn btn-danger">
                                                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                                    <path d="M2.5 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1H3v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h.5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H10a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H2.5zm3 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM8 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7A.5.5 0 0 1 8 5zm3 .5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"/>
                                                    </svg>
                                                    Eliminar
                                                </button>
                                              </form>
                                            </div>

                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div> 
                              
                              
                            </td>
                            
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
```

then, the it doesn`t matter which element I try to delete, because the element that will be deleted is the first element of the table. I don`t know why it happens and how to solve it.

Comment: you will have to set the modal ids dynamically otherwise all ids are the same

Comment: @Aless55 Thank you. I see the problem, but now I don`t know how to do that

Comment: To answer your question we would need to know how the whole blade looks like, you say that you loop over students but your code suggests that you loop over days, what is it?
Other than that you could simply call the modal  id something like `id="{{$day->name}}Modal"` or if there is also an student object with id per student:
`id="student-{{$student->id}}-day-{{$day->name}}Modal"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The var `$day` seems like an object.

Maybe you can try to generate the route like `route('days.destroy', $day->id)`

EDIT:

You need to assign different ID for each modal:

```html
@foreach($days as $day)
                        <tr>
                            
                            <td>{{$day->name}}</td>
                            <td>
                              
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal{{$day->id}}"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path d="M2.5 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1H3v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h.5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H10a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H2.5zm3 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM8 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7A.5.5 0 0 1 8 5zm3 .5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"/>
                                </svg> 
                                Eliminar
                              </button> 

                              <!-- The Modal -->
                                      <div class="modal" id="myModal{{$day->id}}">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                                          <div class="modal-content">

                                            <!-- Modal Header -->
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                              <h4 class="modal-title">¿Desea eliminar?</h4>
                                              <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
                                            </div>

                                            <!-- Modal body -->
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                              Si pulsa el siguiente botón, se eliminará el día. Si cierra esta ventana, no se eliminará.
                                            </div>

                                            <!-- Modal footer -->
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                              <form method="POST" action="{{route('days.destroy',$day)}}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar día">
                                                @csrf
                                                @method('DELETE')
                                                <button class="btn btn-danger">
                                                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                                    <path d="M2.5 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1H3v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h.5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H10a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H2.5zm3 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM8 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7A.5.5 0 0 1 8 5zm3 .5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"/>
                                                    </svg>
                                                    Eliminar
                                                </button>
                                              </form>
                                            </div>

                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div> 
                              
                              
                            </td>
                            
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
```

Comment: I need the var day to be an object.

Comment: Yes, but is the route (form action) being generated as expected?

Comment: Yes. The route works but the problem is when I add a modal. If I delete an element without using modals it works, but when I use modals, it always deletes the first element

Comment: You need to assign a different ID for each modal. Otherwise, it will open always the first declared modal.

Comment: I see what you mean, but, how can I do that?